# Constructor restrictions

Tags: c#, class, restriction

i was wondering if there is a way to restrict a value in construction. Here is my code :

```
class Student : Human 
{
    private double Grade;

    public Student(string FirstName, string LastName, double Grade)
        : base(FirstName, LastName)
    {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Grade = Grade;
    }
}
```

and when i make a new Student i want to restrict the Grade between >= 2.00 and <= 6.00 , like compile error or excepion on runtime. Is there a way ? (Don't worry about other fields FirstName, and LastName)

Comment: Don't think you can make it a compile time error, but, going on the assumption that `Grade` is user input, you can run a check to make sure it's within your range, and then let the user know if that fails.

Comment: Do you really want *double*? or do you want *decimal*?  Remember, double cannot precisely represent fractions that are not powers of two on the denominator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check it and throw an exception *at runtime*, like this:

```
if (grade < 2.00 || grade > 6.00)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("grade");
```

Always put such conditions at the start of the method or constructor. I even put them in their own `#region` (but that's my personal preference):

```
public Student(string firstName, string lastName, double grade)
    : base(firstName, lastName)
{
    #region Contract
    if (grade < 2.00 || grade > 6.00)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("grade");
    #endregion
    this.FirstName = firstName;
    this.LastName = lastName;
    this.Grade = grade;
}
```

However, there is a way to get compile-time warnings for such things using Code Contracts. You can download [Code Contracts on MSDN](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) and there you can also find the documentation. It only integrates with non-Express versions of Visual Studio and is written by Microsoft. It will check whether method calls are likely to adhere to the contract you specify. Your code would then become:

```
using System.Diagnotistics.Contracts;

public Student(string firstName, string lastName, double grade)
    : base(firstName, lastName)
{
    #region Contract
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(grade >= 2.00);
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(grade <= 6.00);
    #endregion
    this.FirstName = firstName;
    this.LastName = lastName;
    this.Grade = grade;
}
```

Comment: +1 for ArgumentOutOfRangeException, but disagree with the region.

Comment: Why not combine into one Requires clause? `Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(grade >= 2.00 && grade <= 6.00);`

Comment: @Andy Code Contracts used to be bad at dealing with compound requires/ensures and invariants. I'm not sure whether that's still the case, but in the interests of that and readability (long lines and such) I split them up.

Answer (score 4):

You can thrown an exception:

```
class Student : Human 
{
    private double Grade;

    public Student(string FirstName, string LastName, double Grade)
        : base(FirstName, LastName)
    {
        if (Grade >= 2 && Grade <= 6) { 
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Grade = Grade;
    }
}
```

If you're using [Microsoft Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) you can do it this was as well:

```
class Student : Human  {
    private double Grade;

    public Student(string FirstName, string LastName, double Grade)
        : base(FirstName, LastName)
    {
        System.Diagnotistics.Contracts.Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(Grade >= 2 && Grade <= 6);

        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Grade = Grade;
    }
}
```

Comment: The condition in your first example is inverted. It throws on grades between 2 and 6 inclusive instead of throwing except on those grades.

Answer (score 1):

There's another option, that might be a bit combersome but will ensure the given ranges, is not to use `double` at all, but create a custom class called `Grade`. Your `Grade` class will contain casts from and to `double`, and will enforce validation.
This means that all Grade validation logic is in the `Grade` struct, and the `Student` class just receives a `Grade` object and doesn't have to worry about it.

```
public struct Grade
{
    public static readonly double MinValue = 2.0;
    public static readonly double MaxValue = 6.0;

    private double value;

    public static explicit operator double(Grade grade)
    {
        return grade.value + MinValue;
    }

    public static explicit operator Grade(double gradeValue)
    {
        if (gradeValue < MinValue || gradeValue > MaxValue)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("gradeValue", "Grade must be between 2.0 and 6.0");

        return new Grade{ value = gradeValue - MinValue };
    }
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
double userInput = GetUserInputForGrade();
Grade grade = (Grade)userInput; // perform explicit cast.
Student student = new Student(firstName, lastName, grade);
```

**Edit:** I've updated the code with @EricLippert's suggestions, to make the class expose its min/max values to a developer.

**Edit 2:** Updated again with @JeppeStigNielsen's suggestion. The `value` field now stores an offset from MinValue, so that a call to `default(Grade)` will return a valid value (equal to MinValue) regardless of whether 0 is inside the valid range.

Comment: But then you lose all operators, all comparison and equality methods, and any method accepting a `double` will no longer accept your `Grade`.

Comment: @Virtlink: So implement those operations on the type Grade if you miss them.

Comment: I like this idea but I would make the constants *public static readonly fields*. Public because we want the user to be able to know when a double is out of range. Static because it's type-wide. And readonly, not constant, because the range might change in the future.

Comment: @EricLippert This struct has the problem that `default(Grade)` (or equivalently `new Grade()`) will create an "illegal" value `0.0` of the `Grade` struct. Your check is not run in that case. One work-around is to store the ***excess*** compared to `2.0` (`MinValue`) in the instance field. So for exapmle if the real grade was `2.5`, you would store `0.5`. Your conversion operators would then have to add (respectively subtract) `MinValue` before they `return`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Excellent point! It is important to remember that the default value of a struct is always a legal value.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Student : Human 
{
    private double Grade;

    public Student(string FirstName, string LastName, double Grade)
        : base(FirstName, LastName)
    {
        if (Grade < 2 || Grade > 6)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Grade must be between 2 and 6");

        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Grade = Grade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Student(string FirstName, string LastName, double Grade)
    : base(FirstName, LastName)
    {
     if(Grade >= 2.0 || Grade <= 6.00)
      throw  new ArgumentException("your message");     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want any chance of compile time cheking you have to use code contracts. They are essentially exceptions at runtime, so equivalent to argument validations with exceptions.

```
public Student(string firstName, string lastName, decimal grade)
{
    Contract.Requires(grade >= 2);
    Contract.Requires(grade <= 6);

    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
    Grade = grade;     
}
```

See this question

[Design by contracts and constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767247/design-by-contracts-and-constructors)

Answer (score -2):

```
class Student : Human 
{
    private double Grade;

    public Student(string FirstName, string LastName, double Grade)
        : base(FirstName, LastName)
    {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Grade = Grade;
        if(Grade >= 2 and Grade <= 6){
            throw new Exception("Incorrect grade input");
    }
}
```

Or throw the relevent exception you want to e.g. ArgumentOutOfException etc...

Comment: The exception is up to the programmer, and since we don't have enough information on why the grades should not be between 1 and 7 should not mean a specific exception should be thrown e.g. ArgumentOutOfException.

Comment: @SpaceApple There's a general rule that you never just throw Exception.  It goes against .Net best practices.

Comment: True. ArgumentException is not valid in this case as well since it might not meet the programmers needs. But I do understand your point.